# Calculate sum of column values for every minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with 4 columns like:

```
Date        Time        Val1     Val2
17-01-2019  09:15:03     -       -118 
17-01-2019  09:15:03     2       -   
17-01-2019  09:15:05     75      -   
17-01-2019  09:15:06     -       -59 
17-01-2019  09:15:06     -       -41 
17-01-2019  09:15:08     64      -   
17-01-2019  09:15:08     -       -39 
17-01-2019  09:15:10     17      -   
17-01-2019  09:15:10     15      -   
17-01-2019  09:15:56     25      -   
17-01-2019  09:15:56     -       -70 
17-01-2019  09:15:57     -       -9 
17-01-2019  09:15:59     5       -   
17-01-2019  09:15:59     19      -   
17-01-2019  09:16:01     26      -   
17-01-2019  09:16:01     -       -7 
17-01-2019  09:16:02     23      -   
17-01-2019  09:16:03     -       -5 
17-01-2019  09:16:05     -       -73 
17-01-2019  09:16:52     -       -15 
17-01-2019  09:16:53     -       -   
17-01-2019  09:16:53     -       -11 
17-01-2019  09:16:55     -       -20 
17-01-2019  09:16:57     -       -21 
17-01-2019  09:16:57     4       -   
17-01-2019  09:16:58     17      -   
17-01-2019  09:17:00     -       -7 
17-01-2019  09:17:00     -       -2 
17-01-2019  09:17:02     -       -41 
17-01-2019  09:17:02     21      -   
17-01-2019  09:17:04     10      -   
17-01-2019  09:17:54     -       -14 
17-01-2019  09:17:54     -       -17 
17-01-2019  09:17:56     -       -8 
17-01-2019  09:17:57     -       -16 
17-01-2019  09:17:57     -       -3 
17-01-2019  09:17:59     -       -31 
17-01-2019  09:17:59     5       -   
18-01-2019  09:15:01     15      45
18-01-2019  09:15:08     24      56
18-01-2019  09:16:23     12      24  
18-01-2019  09:16:01     19      41
```

I need to calculate sum of Val1 and Val2 column for every minute. 
I mean for all the data (Val1 and Val2) for **09:15**, **09:16**, **09:17** so on to be grouped and added

I want my **result** as:

```
Date        Time        Val1     Val2
17-01-2019  09:15:00     222    -336
17-01-2019  09:16:00     70     -152
17-01-2019  09:17:00     36     -139
18-01-2019  09:15:00     39      101
18-01-2019  09:16:00     31      65
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then convert all columns to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and call [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `sum`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time'))
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').resample('1Min').sum()

print (df)
                      Val1   Val2
2019-01-17 09:15:00  222.0 -336.0
2019-01-17 09:16:00   70.0 -152.0
2019-01-17 09:17:00   36.0 -139.0
```

If necessary columns from `DatetimeIndex` use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'Date', df.index.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
df.insert(1, 'Time', df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
#alternative
#df.insert(0, 'Date', df.index.date)
#df.insert(1, 'Time', df.index.time)
df  = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         Date      Time   Val1   Val2
0  17-01-2019  09:15:00  222.0 -336.0
1  17-01-2019  09:16:00   70.0 -152.0
2  17-01-2019  09:17:00   36.0 -139.0
```

Comment: How to do it only on Val2 Column and Keep the last Value of Val1 Column (last value of  Time 09:15,  09:16....)

Comment: @Rohit - Use `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').resample('1Min')['Val1'].last()`

Comment: Ohh Sorry. I mean Sum for Val2 and Last for Val1 Column. Is it possible.

Comment: @Rohit - Sure, change `.resample('1Min')['Val1'].last()` to `.resample('1Min').agg({'Val1': 'last', 'Val2': 'sum'})`

Comment: Ahh. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Sir, When I am working with data for multiple **Date**, garbage datetimes are getting filled. How to solve that.

Comment: @Rohit - What is `garbage dates` ?

Comment: My dataframe ends at 15:30 Hrs and starts as 09:15 Hrs next day. But now I am getting **Datetime** as 2019-01-28 15:31:00, 2019-01-28 15:32:00, 2019-01-28 15:33:00, 2019-01-28 15:34:00..... etc and Val1 and Val2 values as **NaN** until next Day.

Comment: @Rohit - It seems data related problem, are data confidental?

Comment: No Confidential Data Sir, I have just updated the sample data above by adding data for 18th Jan. If we run the above code then data for non valid datetime is appearing.

Comment: @Rohit - Yes, I understand. It is expected, because `resample` create `full DatetimeIndex`, not `discontinuous`

Comment: so last step is `dropna(how='all')`

Comment: @Rohit - Add it by change `.resample('1Min').sum()` to `.resample('1Min').sum().dropna(how='all')`

Comment: Sir, for some date, **month** field is appearing in middle like 2019-**03**-15 15:29:00 and for others **month** field is appearing in end like 2019-05-**03** 15:29:00. Why ?

Comment: @Rohit - Because bad parsing. Need change `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time'))` to `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date') + ' ' + df.pop('Time'), format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')` - specified format for day forsa and then month